# I installed iOS SDK version 16.3.1 using the SPM process, but when I checked on the Facebook developer account, it showed version 0.3.1

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook

**Xcode version**
15.3

**Facebook iOS SDK version**
16.3.1

**Dependency Manager**
CocoaPods

**SDK Framework**
Core

**Goals**
We want to track the events when users see the advertisement of our app. Additionally, when a user clicks on that advertisement, they should be navigated to our application.

**Expected results**
I integrated the iOS SDK version 16.3.1 successfully, and the same version should shown on to the Facebook developer account.

**Actual results**
I integrated the iOS SDK version 16.3.1 successfully, , but on to the Facebook developer account it shows 0.3.1

**Steps to reproduce**
Using Swift Package Manager (SPM)
If your app uses SPM to integrate with the Facebook SDK for iOS, follow these steps.

1. In Xcode, click File > Swift packages > Add package dependency.
2. In Package repository, enter the repository URL: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.
3. In Version, select Up to next major and the default option.
4. Complete the prompts to select the libraries you want to use in your project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sNcB.png)

I’m trying to give the support of iOS 14+ devices using the below methods, while integrating I’m facing some challenges:-

**Swift Package Manager Method:**

After uploading the new SDK with version 16.3.1, it installed successfully. However, the Facebook developer account displays the wrong SDK version number.

Attempting version 14.1.0 resulted in a successful installation on the Facebook developer account, but this version did not support iOS 14+ devices.

**CocoaPods Method:**

The CocoaPods method installed and ran successfully, with events showing on the developer account. However, the Facebook developer account displays the wrong SDK version, likely because it also installed version 16.3.1.